# Getting 'Received fatal alert: handshake_failure' exception when recording through JMeter

Tags: jmeter, handshake

I am getting below error while recording the website through JMeter(2.13).
I am using Java JDK 1.8 installed.
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake - Found using fiddler.
Tried setting 'https.default.protocol=SSLv3' in jmeter.properties file but did not work.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2):

You may have encountered the following JMeter bug: [SSL SNI extension not supported by HttpClient 4.2.6](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57935)

Il will be fixed in JMeter 3.0 as it uses HTTPclient 4.5.2.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the response. I tried the Httpclient 3.1 implementation and it worked.Any idea when JMeter 3.0 will be released?